# javac.exe AST programmatic access example

Tags: java, javac, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to access the Abstract Syntax Tree(AST) inside the javac.exe programmatically? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only since Java 6. [Peter von der Ahé](http://java.sun.com/developer/Meet-Eng/vonderahe/) talks about the two JSRs in [this interview](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/compiler_api.html). Of JSR 199:

> The JSR 199 Compiler API consists of three things: The first one basically allows you to invoke a compiler via the API. Second, the API allows you to customize how the compiler finds and writes out files. I mean files in the abstract sense, since the files the compiler deals with aren't necessarily on the file system. JSR 199's file abstraction allows you to have files in a database, and to generate output directly to memory, for example. Finally, the JSR 199 API lets you collect diagnostics from the compiler in a structured way so that you can easily transform error messages, for instance, into lines in an IDE's editor.

JSR 269 is the annotation processing API.

[This article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html) gives an excellent overview of accessing the [Compiler Tree API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/index.html). The section "[Accessing the Abstract Syntax Tree: The Compiler Tree API](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023040328/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html#accessing-the-abstract-syntax-tree-the-compiler-tree-api)" seems particularly suitable for your question.

Depending on what you're doing, you may also want to look at the [Jackpot Rule Language](http://jackpot.netbeans.org/docs/rule-language.html), which is a standalone refactoring engine that plugins into the Compiler Tree.

Answer (score 6):

Compile and run this with `-cp tools.jar` (where you have to specify the location of your `tools.jar`, obviously).

```
import com.sun.source.util.Trees;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JCTreeTest {
    private static final JavaCompiler javac
            = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StandardJavaFileManager jfm
                = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task
                = javac.getTask(null, jfm, null, null, null,
                  jfm.getJavaFileObjects(args));
        final Trees trees = Trees.instance(task);
        // Do stuff with "trees"
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs for me, though I have not played with the trees stuff myself, so you'll have to [read the javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/) yourself. :-) Good luck!