# Generate Bytecode from AST

Tags: javac, abstract-syntax-tree

[This link](https://blogs.oracle.com/yj/entry/yet_another_way_to_hack) describes how bytecode can be generated from an AST tree.  Basically, it shows how the parsing phase of compilation can be bypassed and the AST be picked up by the java compiler to produce bytecode.

This works well but I would like to be able to generate the AST using javac the way it is without changing its source code and without any framework.  Is this possible and has there been anything done like this before?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197057/javac-exe-ast-programmatic-access-example). The accepted answer links to the compiler tree API, which may be what you need.

Comment: @Eran, thanks.  I talked to the guys at compiler-dev and they said as of now, "there is no way to compile an arbitrary tree created by the user using arbitrary implementions of com.sun.source.tree.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you cannot compile a tree created by the user using the arbitrary implementations of com.sun.source.tree.*.  What can be done though is to print the AST to a string and compile the string in memory using the Java 6 Compiler API.